# How to return a success or fail code from Node.js to Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am building my website with Angularjs and I am testing it with Node js and express. So, I am able to send a json item with information from the contact page form.  But, I do not know How to return a success or fail code from Node.js to Angularjs to redirect to a thank you page.  Also, I need to know how to send the information to my email and save it to a db and how to add a token for the form. I know that I'm using the MEAN stack.  I learn better watch.

Here is my Node js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var formidable = require('formidable');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));    // navigate to where the app reside

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.redirect('Index.html');
});

app.post('/Contact', function (request, response) {
    var frm = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    frm.parse(request, function(err, formData){
    var Name = formData.Name,
        Email= formData.Email,
        Message = formData.Message;
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
        response.end("{'status:' 200}");
    });
});
var port = 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port:  ' + port);
```

and here is my Angularjs:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
        console.log('Im in the controller');
        console.log($scope.formData);       
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : '/Contact',
            data    : $.param($scope.formData), 
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } 
        }).success(function(result, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(result);
            if(result.status == "???"){
                redirectTo: '/Thnkyu';
            }
        }).error(function(result, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
```

Comment: `result.status == "200"`, doesn't work??

Comment: `response.json({ status: 200});`

Comment: When I submit the form; the console shows:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Before it showed:  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED because I had the url portion before I seted the headers and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I submit the form; the console showed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined Before it showed: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED because I had the url portion before I setted the headers and data.

The problem was I use the angularJs $http dependence as shown above; but, it did not work. So, I use the $http dependence like so:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
        console.log($scope.formData);
        $http.post("/contact", $scope.formData)
        .success(function(reponse){
            if(reponse.status == 200)
            console.log('im in')
            $location.path('/thnkyu');
        });
```

and the response from the server is like this:

```
...
if(!eor){
        console.log(eor);
        response.json({status: 200});
    }
```